# python turtle on mac not working

Tags: python, macos, turtle-graphics

I am trying to use a python import of turtle but i get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "turtle.py", line 1, in <module>
    import turtle
  File "/turtle.py", line 32, in <module>
    turtle.pensize(2)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pensize'
```

Does the python come with turtle or i have to download it separately?

My python is 2.7.2

Comment: Are you using the system python? The code you posted works on my EPD Python distribution

Comment: @mbatchkarov what do you mean by system python? I had it on my mac installed already

Comment: I meant the one that your mac came with, but that doesn't appear to be related. See the answer @DSM gave

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You called your file `turtle.py`, so `import turtle` imports your program, not the module you want.

Rename your program and delete any `turtle.py[co]` files.

Comment: I renamed the file and still get the same thing

Comment: If by "the same thing" you mean `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pensize'`, then you're still getting the wrong module.  Type `import imp` and then `print imp.find_module("turtle")` to see what file it's trying to import.

Comment: i got it, i had another file called turtle.pyc and it was conflicting  with the import.

Answer (score 0):

using turtle.py is causing the problem here. scrap that and use this instead

```
import turtle
turtlename = turtle.Turtle()
wn = turtle.Screen()
```

once you have done this use basic turtle comands like

```
turtlename.forward(90)
```